# How store latest xrp price in varaible in python?

Tags: python, binance

I am using binance api in python and am trying to extract the latest price in this line of code.

```
 price = client.get_symbol_info('XRPUSDT')
 print(price)
```

How do I extract the price from the output on the screen. Do I write the output to a file? Or do I loop through the output if so how would I do it.

Comment: Provide and output of the print statement. Does it print the information you are looking for? What errors are you encountering.

Comment: Please add more information so that community can help you back.

Comment: Fixed it. I have to dump the json string. I fixed it. You can close the question.